# Set event on WaitHandle

Tags: c#, multithreading

The System.Threading.Timer class has an override of Dispose which takes a WaitHandle. The idea is once all timer callbacks are complete it sets the waithandle and you know it's safe to shut down.

Unfortunately there's no method on the WaitHandle class to set the event. Looking through the source it acutally uses an import from Kernal32 to set the event.

Is there a framework friendly method to set a WaitHandle? All the examples use a specific implementation of WaitHandle which already has a set method on it. Seems slightly absurd there's no Set or similar on the base class. It exists on the EventWaitHandle one level below.

Comment: Is this question about Timer at all or is this just an example?

Comment: `WaitHandle` is an abstract class. You cannot use it directly, you use one of its concrete subclasses.

Comment: The point is System.Threading.Timer's Dispose takes WaitHandle and then uses a DllImport to Set the event on it. That's the point of base classes, it allows you to pass in any implementation.

Comment: Timer is from the same vendor. It can make use of internal knowledge that you don't have.

Comment: Maybe this is actually a bug in Timer. It uses SetEvent even when you pass in a Mutex. I don't think that's valid.

Comment: It's a bit weird. I allow EventWaitHandle on my method as the base type which allows me to signal that my shutdown is complete. Seeing WaitHandle used on Timer made me think I'd missed something, limiting the variety of WaitHandles that could be signalled, but perhaps not :/

Answer (score 0):

> I allow EventWaitHandle on my method as the base type which allows me to signal that my shutdown is complete.

The modern way to do this is to expose a `Task` that becomes completed when you want to signal something. No need for handles (which are mostly obsolete in .NET) and no need for passing anything in which is architecturally awkward.

A `Task` is like an event but much nicer and more light-weight.

Comment: Not a bug, it cannot dictate whether you use an ARE or an MRE.

Comment: What do you mean by that? It calls SetEvent on a mutex if I read that code correctly.

Comment: You didn't read it correctly.  AutoResetEvent and ManualResetEvent are .NET wrappers for a Windows kernel event object.  The kind that's created with the CreateEvent() winapi function.

Comment: So is calling SetEvent(new Mutex().Handle) a valid thing? Because that's what Timer.Dispose does.

Comment: `[SecuritySafeCritical]
internal void SignalNoCallbacksRunning()
{
    Win32Native.SetEvent(this.m_notifyWhenNoCallbacksRunning.SafeWaitHandle);
}
`

Comment: Well, where do you see the word "mutex" anywhere in that code?

Comment: `new Timer(...).Dispose(new Mutex())`

Comment: That is of course a bug, no point in writing buggy code.  That System.Threading.Timer needs a manual is not a big secret.  They knew this early, then they created System.Timers.Timer :(  It would all look different if they could do it all over again.  But everybody has to start at 1.0, even the big boys.